# go-pythonの使い方を教えてください。

Tags: python, go, python2

いつもお世話になります。
goについて教えてください。github上に公開されている、goからpythonのコードをよぶためのライブラリの利用法がよく分からないのでご教授をお願いします。以下です。

https://github.com/sbinet/go-python

こちらのライブラリは3系では、動かず、2系でうごくようです。間違っていたらすいません。
例えば

// sample.py

```
print "Hello world!"
```

をよびだすためには、go側をどのようにソースを書けば良いのかわからず悩んでいます。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: go-python 自体の `go get` には成功している前提で良いでしょうか？

Comment: go-pythonは成功している前提です。どちらかといえば、呼び出し方法がわからないです。goのソースの書き方はわかります。

Comment: ドキュメントを見ると、pythonのobjectをgoに渡しているのですが、そのobject多分、pythonのファイルをどのようにして設定したら、良いかサンプルソースがないので悩んでいます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

README.md に書いてあるとおり、go-python は基本的に [Python/C API for CPython 2](https://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/index.html) を Go 1 向けに移植したものなので、Python/C API のサンプルコードを探すのが分かりやすいと思います。go-python はどちらかというと Python を拡張するモジュールを Go で書くためのものですが、一応 [`PyRun_SimpleFile`](https://godoc.org/github.com/sbinet/go-python#PyRun_SimpleFile) を使うと外部の Python スクリプトを実行することができます。

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/sbinet/go-python"
)

func init() {
    err := python.Initialize()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
}

func main() {
    err := python.PyRun_SimpleFile("./sample.py")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error)
    }
}
```

---

#### 補足

Python 3 を視野に入れる場合、同じ作者が作っている https://github.com/go-python/gopy の方が良いかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。早速やってみます。